# MongoDB aggregate - filter by subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection with structure like that:

```
[
  {
    name: "name1",
    instances: [{value:1, score:2}, {value:2, score:5}, {value:2.5, score:9}]
  },
  {
    name: "name2",
    instances: [{value:6, score:3}, {value:1, score:6}, {value:3.7, score:5.2}]
  }
]
```

When I want to get all the data from a document, I use `aggregate` because I want each instance returned as a separate document:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{$match:{name:"name1"}}, {$unwind:"$instances"}, {$project:{name:1, value:"$instances.value", score:"$instances.score"}}])
```

And everything works like I want it to.

Now for my question: I want to filter the returned data by score or by value. For example, I want an array of all the subdocuments of `name1` which have a value greater or equal to `2`.
I tried to add to the `$match` object `'instances.value':{$gte:2}`, but it didn't filter anything, and I still get all 3 documents for this query.

Any ideas?

Comment: Help me to understand your problem clearly, do you have a sample expected output?

Comment: @chridam, expected result: `[{name:"name1", value:2, score:5}, {name:"name1", value:2.5, score:9}]`

Comment: Cheers, I believe @yogesh got it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After unwinding `instances` then again used `$match` as below

```
    db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$match": {
    "name": "name1"
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$instances"
}, {
    "$match": {
    "instances.value": {
        "$gte": 2
    }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
    name: 1,
    value: "$instances.value",
    score: "$instances.score"
    }
})
```

Or if you tried `$match` after `project` then used as below

```
 db.collectionName.aggregate([{
     $match: {
     name: "name1"
     }
 }, {
     $unwind: "$instances"
 }, {
     $project: {
     name: 1,
     value: "$instances.value",
     score: "$instances.score"
     }
 }, {
     "$match": {
     "value": {
         "$gte": 2
     }
     }
 }])
```